# How to use a hashmap to set characters equal to different characters?

Tags: java, encryption, hashmap

For an assignment in my compsci class, I need to use hashmaps to convert a message into an encrypted message. We're told to do this by replacing all characters in a given message string with characters in a substitution alphabet that consists of lowercase letters from *a* to *z*. Also, the substitution should be done in alphabetical order.

So for example if we're given the message "hello", our cipher should map *h* to *a*, *e* to *b*, *l* to *c*, and *o* to *d*, giving us the string *abccd*. In theory, it doesn't seem that hard, but I'm having a lot of trouble with the actual conversion of characters. I've put a comment where I was intending to do the actual conversions, but so far all I'm getting returned is a bunch of *a*'s and *b*'s put together. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT: Removed some redundant code thanks to @taha

```
public class Encryption {
    public String encrypt(String message) {
        StringBuilder convertedMessage = new StringBuilder();
        int counter = 0;
        char[] alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();

        HashMap<Character, Character> converter = new HashMap<>();
        String messageholder = message.toLowerCase();
        char[] charMessage = messageholder.toCharArray();

        //this statement is what's giving me an aneurysm
        for (char i : charMessage ) {
            converter.putIfAbsent(i, alphabet[counter]);
            counter++;
        }

        for (Character c : converter.keySet()) {
            char value = converter.get(c);
            convertedMessage.append(value);
        }

        return convertedMessage.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: A `Map` in Java consists of key-value pairs, can you imagine a way to use it in order to map one character to another one?

Comment: that's what I'm trying to do in the putifAbsent statement, but it doesn't seem to be working and I can't figure out why. It's supposed to iterate through the alphabet character array I've made and assign each character in the message to a value in that array.

Comment: First of all `String` is an immutable object. It means once you created it, you cannot change its value. So operations like `toLowerCase` do not modify the String they are called on. Instead they return a new `String` instance. As clue about your problem; I would suggest looking at the second loop. Because you are iterating over a set. But your String can include same character multiple times.

Comment: @deHaar sorry forgot to use the @

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code seems to have 2 major issues:

1. There is an attempt to remove non-alphabet characters from the input message
2. The second loop is not needed at all, and the encrypted message should be built while iterating the input message as soon as the cipher character is selected.

```java
public static String encrypt(String message){
    StringBuilder convertedMessage = new StringBuilder();
    int counter = 0;
    char[] alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();

    HashMap<Character, Character> converter = new HashMap<>();
    // keep only lower-case English letters
    message = message.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", "").toLowerCase();

    for (char i : message.toCharArray()) {
        converter.putIfAbsent(i, alphabet[counter++]);
        convertedMessage.append(converter.get(i));
    }

    return convertedMessage.toString();
}

// Test
System.out.println(encrypt("Hello,World!"));
```

Output:

```
abccefehcj
```

---

However, the code above updates the counter *each time* a character from the input message is looked up and therefore some values may be skipped. For example, `d` is skipped because `counter` is incremented for the second `l` in `hello`. Similarly, `g` is skipped for the second occurrence of `o` in `world`, etc.

So, it could make sense to use method `Map::computeIfAbsent` instead of `Map::putIfAbsent` which calls a function to modify the counter only when needed.

In this case, `counter` should be implemented as an effectively final variable because it is used in a lambda function - either as an array or `AtomicInteger`:

```java
int[] counter = new int[1]; // or AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

for (char i : charMessage ) {
    converter.computeIfAbsent(i, k -> alphabet[counter[0]++]);
// for AtomicInteger converter.computeIfAbsent(i, k -> alphabet[counter.getAndIncrement()]);
    convertedMessage.append(converter.get(i));
}
```

Then the encrypted string for `Hello World!` looks like this:

```
abccdedfcg
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response! Although I'm still having a problem; in your example, the hello world string should return abccd for the hello part (at least according to the specifications of my assignment), but instead it returns abcce. Why is that? And how could I change it?

Comment: @electricnerd, I also noticed that and provided the update. briefly: `computeIfAbsent` is at help here.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! I also appreciate the explanation, it definitely helped demystify the reason why some of the letters were skipped.